# What regular maintenance should I do on my SSD (primary Windows drive)?

Tags: ssd, maintenance

Should I do anything in addition to ChkDsk /f  ?

And how often?

Answer (score 1):

Newer SSD's don't need maintenance. Especially, do not defrag - they don't have fragmentation problems. On older ones, you may need to ensure 'Trim' is active.